# How do I ensure that T thread can access n resources without deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, deadlock

Suppose I have threads t1,t2,t3......t10 and I need to access the printer and scanner, order is first scan and then print using this threads so how do I ensure that t1,t2...t10(by multiple users) can access the scanner or printer without deadlock.

t1 finishes his job of scanning and waiting for printer and now t2 is doing job of printing the doc. So how do I ensure that t1 should not interrupt the job t2.  now t2 finishes his job of printing same user wants to scan the another document but it is not released by t1. so deadlock between t1 and t2, t1 wants printer and t2 wants scanner but they already holding the other ones resource.

Comment: Your title and content don't say the same thing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think there could be a deadlock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> t1 finishes his job of scanning and waiting for printer and now t2 is doing job of printing the doc. So how do I ensure that t1 should not interrupt the job t2.

A good way to implement such a mechanism is to use a queue, for example a thread safe [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and have 2 consumer threads:

- the Printer Thread that takes jobs from the printerQueue
- the Scanner Thread that takes jobs from the scannerQueue

Then your T0...T10 simply put jobs in one of the queues and wait (or not) for them to be executed when the Printer/Scanner is ready.

By doing that you remove the need to lock on the client/producer side and let the consumer side (Printer and Scanner) to manage their jobs.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, but I have deadlock between them like t1 wants resource which is already with t2 and t2 wants resource hold by t1.

Comment: @Amol In the scenario I describe, t1 and t2 don't have a direct access to the resources. Instead they simply put a task in a queue (whenever they want and without locking) and let the resource decide when it is ready to process that task.

Comment: @Amol The javadoc (link in my answer) has a basic example of a producer / consumer scenario. You can certainly find more complete examples on SO.

Comment: Just going through, Thank you very much, it is really helpful for me

Comment: This is the proper way to do it. Always avoid manual locking/synchronization wherever possible.

Answer (score 3):

1. use one single lock
2. if you decide on multiple locks always acquire them in the same sequence (example always take printer lock first then scanner lock)

Comment: Or 3. Only hold one lock at a time, the one on the resource you're using at that time.